# Can I use cluster in a node.js express app still spawn child_process workers for specific requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multiprocessing

**EDIT:**
I'm simplifying my question, because while [@saintedlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263251/saintedlama)'s response is helpful information, it is tangental to what I'm trying to understand about using more than a single node process.

**The crux of it is:**  How do I, or can I, manage manually spawned child processes, given the app is using already running using [node's native cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)?

Original question(s) below

---

> I have an express.js app, the main function is to accept http requests and serve http responses via some MongoDB queries. For performance, the app uses [node's native cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), and is spawned across available CPUs as worker processes at app start.
>
> I now have some specific queries that may be long running  - connecting to external services and APIs.
>
> 1. Is it worth spawning these specific queries to their own workers (using [node's child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) )?
> 2. And if so, how will this be affected by the existing use of cluster?
> 3. Alternatively (or as well) if I set up a persistent worker queue using something like [Monq](https://github.com/scttnlsn/monq) or [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) - and given I'm using cluster, how can I control which process handles the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Spawning long running queries to some forked worker may, depending on the work done in node.js JavaScript processing, not yield any benefit.

Node.js does all IO processing (the queries are IO) in a dedicated thread (pool) in the background. So your node.js JavaScript process is not blocked while the database system processes the query.
In case that you're doing a lot of query result post processing in JavaScript it may yield benefits, since while post processing in JavaScript code the JavaScript processor is blocked.

Using a job queue for doing these queries async has benefits since you can start developing with job processors in the same process and you will later have the possibility to easily scale out by deploying job processors to dedicated machines in your environment. But: Be careful with this approach since having very large query results may slow down your job queue.

Comment: So spawning a child worker process would suit CPU intensive queries, but not necessarily long running IO to another service? How would I manage spawning CPU intensive processes given the cluster environment?